# syntax highlighting in pydb

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to enable syntax highlighting in pydb command shell (standalone or inside ipython)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People say winpdb is way faster. Switched to it instead.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @hek2mgl As far as I remember, winpdb has syntax highlighting and does approximately the same thing.

Comment: As of today, they [say](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/pydb/features.html) they support ipython, so there must be a way to accomplish this but it is not relevant for me any longer.

Answer (score 1):

pydb has been superceded by [trepan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan) or [trepan3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan3k) and this has both syntax highlighting for light and dark backgrounds, tab completion and can be [used inside ipython](http://python2-trepan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/entry-exit.html#calling-the-debugger-from-an-interactive-python-shell).

About the name change, when Polish-speaking people tell your name is unpronounceable, it's time to change the name.